# Looking for network monitoring software for Win7 x64 (similar to the one included with Sunbelt personal firewall)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, firewall, monitoring, windows-firewall

I've upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7 (64bit) and I found that the very convenient Sunbelt Kerio Personal Firewall will not work on this version.

I hear the Windows 7 firewall is good enough(even though it never prompts for outbound connections) but Kerio had a nice network monitor feature which showed all applications with inbound and outbound connections and the current speed and bytes transferred for each one.

Is there any software out there that can give me similar monitoring 
as what Kerio does?

TCPView is almost as good, but doesnt show transfer statistics.

Edit :

I found that the Windows Resource Monitor can show the information I need, so my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) for about a year.  It works great.  Here is [what it can do.](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=40&Itemid=43)  I built my firewall on an old PC with minimal resources (512 MB RAM, 40 GB hard disk, old Asus mainboard with built in components, no optical drive).  I bought 10 Intel network cards for $30 and used 3 of them for this firewall.  It took me an hour or so to build the system and get pfSense installed, and then a week or so, off and on, tuning it and adjusting it to how I wanted it.  pfSense it built on the Linux kernel.

Comment: While this sounds like a decent solution for building a firewall, it really doesn't answer the question. The question is looking for a firewall to run on his Windows 7 PC with better diagnostics than the standard Windows 7 firewall.

Comment: Fair enough...  But everyone, including rep_movsd, can benefit from enhancing their overall firewall protection.  My solution would in fact meet his needs and serve to answer his question.